# Is there a way to check whether a cell is highlighted(formatted so background is yellow) in an .xlsx file in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to know if there are any libraries out there that can tell whether a cell's formatting includes a background color or not.

Reading an excel file in pandas does not seem to retain the format of the excel file's cells as a dataframe. The excel file I am working on has one highlighted cell per row.
I need to write a program that reads through the excel file by index number and finds the highlighted cell and reads its contents(string).

The cells were manually highlighted and they do not have any significant mutual features by which I could extract them by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **openpyxl** library allows a developer to apply conditional formatting rules: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html